# Deep nested document search in Solr

Tags: search, solr

I have been working with Solr sub/child documents index/search without problem.  Now we are facing requirements to search deep nested (grandchild, great grand child and so on) fields. I have no problem indexing them in the nested structure in Solr. But I couldn't make it work to search fields in deep nested fields. Below is a piece of data I use for testing. "sub2", "sub3" and "sub4" are nest paths. I am using Solr 8.8.2 (with Solrj).

[

```
{   "id": "1_1",

    "hierarchy": 1,

    "X1_11_str": "10001",

    "X1_12_text": "ancester one",

    "sub2": [

        {   "id": "1_1_2_1",

            "hierarchy": 2,

            "X2_21_text": "child one",

            "sub3": [

                "id": "1_1_2_1_3_1",

                "hierarchy": 3,

                "X3_31_text": "grand one",

                "sub4": [

                    {"id": "1_1_2_1_3_1_4_1",

                     "hierarchy": 4,

                     "X4_41_text": "great grand one",

                     "X4_42_int": 1,

                     "X4_43_str": "red"

                    },

                    {"id": "1_1_2_1_3_1_4_2",

                     "hierarchy": 4,

                     "X4_41_text": "great grand two",

                     "X4_42_int": 2,

                     "X4_43_str": "blue"

                    }

                ]

            ]

        }

    ]

}
```

]

On the root document, there is "sub2" subdocument.   On Sub2 document, there is "sub3" subdocument, and so is for sub3 and sub 4. I wanted to search on sub4 document field but return root documents. Here are my queries:

1. {!parent hierarchy=1}"X4_42_int":1 AND "X4_43_str":"red"

   it returns root document with "id":"1_1".  This is correct.
2. {!parent hierarchy=1}"X4_42_int":1 AND "X4_43_str":"blue"

   it still returns root document with "id":"1_1".

   I understand this is because I ask for root document as result. But this is not I expected. I would like a query that return nothing since there is no sub4 documents match the search.

Could anyone help with the right query syntax?

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Not sure how strict you requirements are, but searching with such deep nesting is not what Solr is usually used for. If possible consider a flatter approach.

Comment: @Wiszh Thanks for the comments.  The query result needs to be per expect although the indexing structure doesn't have to be nested.  I thought about flatten index structure as well but couldn't see how it would solve the issue. It adds more complexity when you consider combining other query clause on sub2, sub3 attributes. Please advise.